# Консольная команда из php скрипта

Tags: php, centos

Разбираюсь с CentOS, вопрос такой. У меня проект написаный на php, по логике которого мне нужно автоматизировать делать некоторые действия командной строки. Например создание нового пользователя. С командной строкой вроде разобрался, но как мне выполнять эти команды внутри php скрипта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с помощью функции exec() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php